# How to get Node.js subpath imports in built declaration file to work

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a module, `module-a`, using Typescript v5.1.6. It has a single [subpath import](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-imports), `#utils`, used in the module. When I compile this module with declaration files enabled as required by dependents, the import is not re-written in both the emitted JS and the declaration file (this is expected).

The issue is that in both the declaration file as viewed from the module, and when importing the module in another project, that subpath import does not resolve when building the other project, and in VSCode.

How do I get this to work?

###### Additional Notes

- If I add this module as a dependency of another project, and that project has a subpath import of the same name, Typescript incorrectly resolves the import statement in `module-a` to the parent project's subpath import.

###### Module File Structure

```
.
├── build/
│   ├── utils/
│   │   ├── index.mjs
│   │   └── index.d.ts
│   ├── index.mjs
│   └── index.d.ts
├── src/
│   ├── utils/
│   │   └── index.mts
│   └── index.mts
├── package.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

###### `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node16",
    "lib": ["ESNext"],
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["./node_modules"]
}
```

###### `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "module-a",
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.6.1",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./build/index.d.mts",
      "default": "./build/index.mjs"
    }
  },
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf build && tsc"
  },
  "imports": {
    "#utils": "./build/utils/index.mjs"
  }
}
```

###### Resulting Declaration File

```
import type { ModuleAType } from "#utils";
export declare const testValue: ModuleAType;
```

###### Error

[image: screenshot of error]